# Yum Install failing install libgs-dev

Tags: chef-infra, yum, apt-get

I have the following I wish to perform

```
apt-get install libgs-dev
```

The issue is my provisioning uses `yum`.

```
Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for libgs-dev
```

I am looking for the `yum` variant of `libgs-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `libgs-devel`. That should be the correct package for RHEL-based operating systems.